# add dynamic values to objects with javascript similar to php

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to add values ​​to my javascript object dynamically, this is what is doing

```
var data = {"clave1":"valor1","clave2":"valor2"};
var options = {"data":{}};
$.each(data,function(c,v){
options.data.{c} = v;
});
```

What I want is that
 **options** are so

```
options = {"data":{"clave1":"valor1",...}};
```

Comment: please ask in english.

Comment: Hola. Puedes ir a [SO en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) si prefieres, o traducir tu pregunta.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not English.

Comment: simply change to `options.data[c] = v;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JS, you need to use brackets to add key-value pairs

```js
var data = {
  "clave1": "valor1",
  "clave2": "valor2"
};
var options = {
  "data": {}
};
$.each(data, function(c, v) {
  options.data[c] = v;
});

console.log(options)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You don't need jQuery for doing this, you can use the function `Object.keys` and then loop using the function `forEach`:

```js
var data = {
  "clave1": "valor1",
  "clave2": "valor2"
};
var options = {
  "data": {}
};

Object.keys(data).forEach(k => options.data[k] = data[k])

console.log(options)
```

And finally, using the function `Object.assign`

```js
var data = {
  "clave1": "valor1",
  "clave2": "valor2"
};
var options = {
  "data": Object.assign({}, data)
};

console.log(options)
```

Comment: Or just use `options.data = data`.

Comment: @str probably the OP wants to avoid same reference in memory

Comment: Then use `options.data = Object.assign({}, data)`.

Comment: @str that's a good approach!

Answer (score 0):

Appending new values to objects is simple! Objects are really like arrays but can have strings as keys! For example:

```
var obj = {};
obj["data"] = {};
obj["data"]["clave1"] = "valor1";
```

So all you would have to do is make sure that you know the name of the parameter! You can also do this:

```
var str = "clave1";
var str2 = "valor1";
var obj = {};
obj["data"] = {};
obj["data"][str] = str2;
```